# console logs of red5 on ubuntu running as a service

Tags: ubuntu, red5

I have a java based tomcat server(Red5) which is running as a service(/etc/init.d/red5) in Ubuntu.

I am not able to find the console(java system out) logs. Is there a default place for ubuntu console logs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thank you
firemonk

Answer (score 0):

Likely /var/log/red5 or /var/log/tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Console logging is turned on by default in red5 and is configured via the red5/conf/logback.xml file (look for CONSOLE). The items destined for the console will be in the red5.log for the most part, but some items are lost when the server starts up before the loggers are in-place. These messages used to be located in the /var/log/messages file on unix based systems, but these days I'm not certain as to where they go by default.